# Object has no attribute '__getitem__' (class instance?)

Tags: python, class

It might be a very simple question but I am very confused with where I am going right now. Here is a very basic class:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, price):
        self.book = {'title':title, 'price':price}
```

And when I run this:

```
book = Book('foo', 300)
book['price']
```

It spits out:

```
TypeError: 'Book' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I know that it's not the conventional way of initializing an instance since I am using a dictionary. But I wonder why that code is spitting out a TypeError. How do I go about solving this issue?
Thank you in advance.

ps. The book instance's type is class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because a class is not a dict object.
Accessing properties on a instance of a class is done via the dot operator.

```
book.book['price'] 
>> 300
```

If you want to access keys within your dict directly on your class instance you would have to implement the `__getitem__` method on your class.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.book[key]

book['price']
>> 300
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. **book** is an object of class **Book** because you initialized it that way.

```
book = Book('foo', 300)
book['price']
```

Try

`print book.book['price']`

So you want to access a dictionary called **book** of an object referenced as **book** and you want to extract the value of **price** from the dictionary.

Usually [] operator looks for `__getitem__()` method and passes the requested key as an argument. Łukasz R. has shown how to do that. Dictionaries perform a key lookup while arrays find the slice or index.

It is explained in details here : https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Now because you're creating a class here, why do you want to create a separate dictionary for native must-have attributes of the class. Create attributes like the following example:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, price):
        self.title = 'foo'
        self.price = 300

book = Book('foo', 300)
print book.title
```

Answer (score 3):

`book.book['price']` would work.
For accessing proxy member you'll have to implement `__getitem__` magic method.

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, price):
        self.book = {'title':title, 'price':price}
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.book[item]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, price):
        self.book = {'title':title, 'price':price}              

book = Book('foo', 300)
print book.book['price']
```